# How to remove the pink edit box?

Tags: support, bug, editing

When editing answers and questions on Math Stack Exchange, I always see a pink box in which it is written 'How to Edit'. Now the problem with this box is that it hides the "Save edits" button, so I am unable to save my edits.

Is there a way in which this box can be removed,, or at least shifted so that I can save my edits? Kindly suggest a way to do so. I have pasted the information given in the pink box. Its exact title is "How to Format".

► fix grammatical or spelling errors
► clarify meaning without changing it
► correct minor mistakes
► add related resources or links
► always respect the original author
How to Format
► create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~

```
like so
```

► add language identifier to highlight code

```
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

► put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► *italic* or **bold**

► quote by placing > at start of line

► to make links

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I will try to send screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just went to StackOverflow where I have never edited a post before, and tried to edit a post. On the right was this notice, which looks like your description-

[image]

However it did not cover my "Save Edits" button. I noticed that if I change the zoom setting on the webpage, the box moves. Maybe you can do this to move the box out of the way. Another thing is that the box acts differently if I click on "Disable Responsiveness" at the bottom of the page:

[image]

By differently, I mean that the box scrolls with the rest of the content (instead of always staying on the screen). You can also try the mobile site (button is above the "Disable Responsiveness" button), even if you're on a computer. Hopefully one of these will solve your problems.

Comment: yes this was the exact same box, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Gingerbread well, it wasn't $\color{pink}{pink}$, so I wasn't 100% sure. Glad to help :)